# SharedPreferences save bg color error

Tags: java, android, android-sharedpreferences

hi i have problem with save the bg color idont know whay he dont get the code :

```
        mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.colourValue);
```

he say "colorvalue" in red. i need your help here here the java code :

```
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnred,btngreen,btnblue,btnpluse,btnsave;
    private LinearLayout mlinearLayout;
    private TextView tv;
    int point = 0;
    public SharedPreferences sp,prefs;
    private int progress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String textValue= prefs.getString("textValue", "0");

        mlinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String colourValue = sp.getString("colourValue", "WHITE");
        mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.colourValue);

        btnred = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cred);
        btnblue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cblue);
        btngreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cgreen);
        btnpluse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
        tv.setText(textValue);
        btnred.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnpluse.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnblue.setOnClickListener(this);
        btngreen.setOnClickListener(this);


        }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btnred == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("colourValue","RED");
            editor.commit();

        }
        else if (btngreen == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("colourValue","GREEN");
            editor.commit();
        }
        else if (btnblue == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("colourValue","BLUE");
            editor.commit();


        }
        else if (btnpluse== v){
            point++;
            tv.setText("" + point);

        }
        else if (btnsave == v){
            Toast.makeText(this,"btn clickd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("textValue",tv.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

and here is image of the problem 
[image: image of the error]

Comment: you can use as ` Color.WHITE`

Comment: sry i dont understand what you meen

Comment: `Color."your color"` returns integer value and you are passing String. so just try as above i mentioned

Comment: itry it bro its still dont save the last color i click :/ sry for my noobi im student just begin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with given updates:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    private Button btnred,btngreen,btnblue,btnpluse,btnsave;
    private LinearLayout mlinearLayout;
    private TextView tv;
    int point = 0;
    public SharedPreferences sp,prefs;
    private int progress;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE);
        String textValue= prefs.getString("textValue", "0");

        mlinearLayout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int colourValue = sp.getInt("colourValue", Color.WHITE);
        mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(colourValue);

        btnred = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cred);
        btnblue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cblue);
        btngreen = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cgreen);
        btnpluse = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnadd);
        btnsave = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv) ;
        tv.setText(textValue);
        btnred.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnpluse.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnblue.setOnClickListener(this);
        btngreen.setOnClickListener(this);


        }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (btnred == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt("colourValue", Color.RED);
            editor.commit();

        }
        else if (btngreen == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt("colourValue", Color.GREEN);
            editor.commit();
        }
        else if (btnblue == v){
            mlinearLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putInt("colourValue", Color.BLUE);
            editor.commit();


        }
        else if (btnpluse== v){
            point++;
            tv.setText("" + point);

        }
        else if (btnsave == v){
            Toast.makeText(this,"btn clickd",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("save", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
            editor.putString("textValue", tv.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope will help you!

Comment: bro first of all ty for your helo sec im sure im doind somthing wrong becuz its still dont work plz look in the pic and tell me what i do wrong : https://s29.postimg.org/a3za3syhz/image.jpg                    https://s23.postimg.org/60srsuqjv/image.jpg

Comment: i still ahve the same problem im sure im doing somthing wrong like you put  "context.getSharedPreferences" but he dont let me to put "context" look  https://s23.postimg.org/foanpk8m3/334.jpg

Comment: Here you can call directly getSharedPreference() from activity. See update!

Comment: ok the problem with "colorvalue" fix thx but he still dont save the bg color meybe the problem in the save code?    plz look if i the save code is good: https://s29.postimg.org/jrfuev57r/5522.jpg

Comment: Try re-installing app! It may be because before you are saving it as `String` and now as `int`

Comment: i do it and still same problem i think i know what the problem but i need your help i use " public SharedPreferences sp,prefs;" prefs for saving counter int and naw i see thet i want to use sp for color its ok ? or i need use prefs for save color to? becuse her :        SharedPreferences *sp* = getSharedPreferences("saveColour", MODE_PRIVATE);
        int colorValue = *prefs*.getInt("colorValue", Color.TRANSPARENT);  i think i use it wrong aswell in the btn clolor save   https://s30.postimg.org/aux0dn5xd/112211.jpg                     https://s28.postimg.org/g4ja6z60t/5522.jpg

Comment: Bro, you are saving value with key `saveColor` and getting with `saveColour`, please use the static values for key string.

Comment: Use `SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("saveColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);`

Comment: plz bro i really dont understand what i do wrong i where i need to change the value key? you can edit it up and show me plz?

Comment: after i do SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("saveColor", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); int the btn color the app crush

Comment: Just copy and paste my code, this is your solution.